# Where do I find the WPS Pin for my Brother Printer?

Tags: windows, pin, brother-printer, wps

Getting a message on my windows computer to put in the WPS Pin. I looked on the printer and in the manual, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Looks like I was trying to add the WiFi Direct Printer. 
https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/163273

Once I went back and did a wireless setup using the Download on the Brother website, it worked. I suggest following videos on YouTube. This worked for my MFCL2710dw. Probably works for other models as well.